# Newman automation via bamboo

Tags: automation, bamboo, postman, newman

I am running my postman collections through newman on demand. I have my collection stored on bitbucke. Please help me how to automate running my collection using bamboo and get email notification .

Answer (score 0):

Get your collection as artifacts then you can simply run 
newman -c postman-json.collection (this should be available as artifacts)